# Printing a copy of a given 4 digit number but every prime digit is followed by the number which is one greater than it

Tags: c

So I've been trying to create a program which asks the user for a 4 digit number, and prints it's copy but every prime digit is just followed by a number just greater than it. (Eg. 2345 becomes 2334456)

So what I tried was first finding storing all the digits and then printing them out as strings, followed by the next number if any of them were prime using if statements. Now this seems to give a different output than I'd expect. 2345 gives 23235656 for example. Where did I go wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    unsigned int userinput;
    unsigned int onesplace;
    unsigned int tensplace;
    unsigned int hundredsplace;
    unsigned int thousandsplace;
    printf("Please print your number /n");
    scanf("%u", &userinput);
    onesplace = userinput%10;
    tensplace = ((userinput-onesplace/10))%10;
    hundredsplace = ((userinput - onesplace -10*tensplace)/100)%10;
    thousandsplace = ((userinput - onesplace - 10*tensplace - 100*hundredsplace)/1000);
    printf("%u", thousandsplace);

    if ((thousandsplace == 2)||(thousandsplace == 3)||(thousandsplace == 5)||(thousandsplace == 7)) {
        unsigned int newnum = thousandsplace + 1;
        printf("%u", newnum);
    }
    printf("%u", hundredsplace);
    if ((hundredsplace == 2)||(hundredsplace == 3)||(hundredsplace == 5)||(hundredsplace == 7)) {
        unsigned int newnum2 = hundredsplace + 1;
        printf("%u", newnum2);
    }
    printf("%u", tensplace);
    if ((tensplace == 2)||(tensplace == 3)||(tensplace == 5)||(tensplace == 7)) {
        unsigned int newnum3 = tensplace + 1;
        printf("%u", newnum3);
    }
    printf("%u", onesplace);
    if ((onesplace == 2)||(onesplace == 3)||(onesplace == 5)||(onesplace == 7)) {
        unsigned int newnum4 = onesplace + 1;
        printf("%u", newnum4);
    }
}
```

Comment: So what output did you get for say `2345`? Also you may want to check whether the digits (`oneplace`, `tenplace` etc.) are correctly calculated or not

Comment: Please indent your code properly before posting. It's not others job to do so.

Comment: @kaylum because it's the digit one greater than 3 and it's a digit in the original input itself.

Comment: @kuro thank you, just realized that I calculated tensplace was wrong

Comment: `(userinput-onesplace/10)` looks weird. Try `((userinput-onesplace)/10)` or `(userinput/10)`.

Comment: Oops, that is the solution. Will make an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are miscalculating the tensplace, essentially forgetting to divide the tens value by 10.

Change `(userinput-onesplace/10)` to `(userinput/10)`.

Then with an input of 2345 you get output

```
Please print your number /n2334456
```

The probably unwanted "/n", visible here in the single output line because I used https://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_c_online.php (with is non-interactively provided standard input), is a separate unrelated problem.